# nginx running in docker swarm on azure is not responding after a restart

Tags: azure, nginx, docker-swarm, azure-container-service

I am running a small docker swarm cluster on azure. I deployed a nginx container as a reverse proxy. Works great with no problems. If it runs for a hour or so and I need to update the config I remove the stack, change nginx.conf and deploy the stack again. After that for some reason it is not receiving any requests or atleast what I get is a timeout in my browser.

If I remove all stacks, reboot my hosts and redeploy every stack again it works again until the next time I update my nginx stack.

I attached to the nginx container and used `nslookup` to check if the web app I am reverse proxying to is accessible. And that seems to work all. I suppose the problem is more on the azure vm side?

I am unsure where the problem might be. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this cluster deployed using Azure container services.

Comment: Using Azure Linux VM. Also happens if running 1 manager and no worker nodes only. So basically single host swarm :-(